# How to update field with initial value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a wallet app, and right now I'm working on updating the initial value field on the wallet. So this is an example and I will provide all code down below.

The user creates a wallet with an initial balance of 300

Then user creates an income transaction of 30

Then user creates an expense transaction of 15

So now the wallet balance is 315, right?

Now, when I go to update my wallet, I can see the value of 300 as the initial balance, I change it to 400, and now the wallet balance should be 415, right? Because I had income - expense 15 as result plus new initial value as 400 that is 415. And now, if user again want to update initial value, the value in field should be 400, then if user change it to 500, wallet balance should be 515

How I can achieve that from this example?

`Wallet entity`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wallet")
public class Wallet {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "wallet_id")
private Long id;

@NotBlank(message = "Please, insert a wallet name")
private String walletName;

@NotNull(message = "Please, insert a amount")
private Double initialBalance;

private Double walletBalance;

private Double totalBalance;
```

`Save income and save expense services`

```
@Override
public void saveExpense(Transaction transaction, Long walletId, Long userId) {
    Wallet wallet = walletService.getWalletById(walletId);

    double amount = transaction.getAmount();
    amount = (wallet.getWalletBalance() == null ? wallet.getInitialBalance(): wallet.getWalletBalance()) - amount;
    wallet.setWalletBalance(amount);

    System.out.println("Wallet balance after expense " + wallet.getWalletBalance());

    transaction.setTransactionType(TransactionType.EXPENSE);

    this.transactionRepository.save(transaction);
}

@Override
public void saveIncome(Transaction transaction, Long walletId, Long userId) {
    Wallet wallet = walletService.getWalletById(walletId);

    double amount = transaction.getAmount();
    amount += wallet.getWalletBalance() == null ? wallet.getInitialBalance(): wallet.getWalletBalance();
    wallet.setWalletBalance(amount);

    System.out.println("Wallet balance after income " + wallet.getWalletBalance());

    transaction.setTransactionType(TransactionType.INCOME);

    this.transactionRepository.save(transaction);
}
```

Comment: what is the issue with the code? Are you not getting desired results?